# Limiting login via access.conf not working

Tags: pam, debian-wheezy

I'm running Debian Wheezy and having a rough time getting /etc/security/access.conf changes to apply. Tangentially, I believe there could be an issue with PAM in general as I have been unable to get changes in limits.conf to stick.

My systems are setup to authenticate against an LDAP server. I want to limit the users that can log in to a couple of local users and members of a couple LDAP groups.

I've added the following to /etc/pam.d/sshd and /etc/pam.d/login:

```
account  required     pam_access.so
```

My access.conf looks like this:

```
+ : local_user1 local_user2 ldap_group1 ldap_group2 : ALL
- : ALL : ALL
```

I know this can be accomplished via sshd_config, but it's become a matter of principle at this point. As I mentioned above, I'm wondering if there isn't something going on with PAM.

Comment: Does `getent group ldap_group1` return a reasonable result?

Comment: Yep. The problem is users other than those listed and not members of the listed groups are still able to log in.

Answer (score 1):

`UsePAM` in /etc/ssh/sshd_config is required for sshd to pay attention to PAM settings.